# How to stop downloading app updates when connected in Mobile data?

Tags: lumia, app-update, lumia-amber

I am using Nokia Lumia 520. I need to control downloading application updates. When i connected in WiFi, i started downloading updates(partially completed). But when i came out of the WiFi range, it's started downloading updates from mobile data. Simply, i want to set to download updates, only when i connected in WiFi. Is it possible?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can cancel an active download by tap-and-holding it (shows a context menu).

Comment: Are you referring to phone updates or application updates? As far as I am aware application updates never take place automatically.

Comment: @karancan - I meant application updates. I started manually to download. During downloading, if i move out of WiFi range and switched on mobile data, the remaining/partial updates started downloading.

Comment: @pleinolijf - Thanks. When i tap-and-holding, i can see pause/cancel option (i guess, pause option is added in amber update). Now I can control download by pausing it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 will allow the user to explicitly pick the following:

> Option to update store apps when only on Wi-Fi

The above is listed as a feature available in the Windows Phone 8.1 preview to developers.

[The entire list is published here.](http://sinclairinat0r.com/2014/02/15/more-features-to-look-forward-to-in-windows-phone-8-1/)

Answer (score 2):

There's an article on the *how-to* section of the Windows Phone website, namely [**How can I minimize my data usage?**](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/how-can-i-minimize-my-data-usage). The article gives several tips and this one might be helpful to you:

**Prevent cellular data usage when Wi-Fi connectivity is limited**

> If your phone is connected to a Wi-Fi network and can't complete a task because connectivity becomes limited, you can determine whether or not your phone will use cellular data to finish the task. For more info, see Cellular settings.

1. In the App list, tap Settings > Cellular.
2. Tap For limited Wi-Fi connectivity, and then tap Don't use cellular data.

**Notes**

- This setting may not appear on your phone, depending on how your phone is set up by the manufacturer or your mobile operator.
- To have this setting, your phone must be running Windows Phone software version 8.0.10211.204 or later. See How do I update my phone software? for more info about how to update your phone.

Comment: this is Nokia Lumia 520, my latest update was 'Amber'. I will check for the Cellular features once I download new updates.